# Java Comparing numbers and displaying largest, comparing strings and displaying lexiographically first

Tags: java

**I need to create two different programs. One that does the following:**

Enter your first number: 15

Enter your second number: 25

25 is larger than 15

and a second separate one that does the following:

Enter the first string: apple

Enter the second string: bananas

apple comes before bananas lexiographically

**This is what I tried for the first one:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClosedLab03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
        int firstNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
        int secondNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        int result;
        if (firstNumber > secondNumber)
        {
            result = System.out.println(firstNumber +" is larger than " + secondNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            result = System.out.println(secondNumber + " is larger than " firstNumber);
        }
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I don't really know what. In terms of comparing the strings, I really don't know how to compare them lexicographically. Our textbook shows us how to compare two strings and say whether or not they are the same, but not how to compare them and display which one is lexicographically first.

Comment: Lexicographical comparison of Numbers is easier to do if they are Strings.  To that end, consider the function in the Integer class [`.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString()).  That said, this may be completely wrong for the approach the instructor desires you to take for this homework problem.  You may wish to read [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/40980) from Programmers.SE's meta site.

Comment: Thanks for giving me that link about the students with homework. I do want to understand, but my TA is unfortunately only available when I'm in another class, and the Java help lab people don't help with concepts and have extremely limited availability. If you have any other resources for REALLY new-to-programming people, I'd appreciate any tips. The book we have isn't explaining things well and the Oracle docs seem to assume you have some other basic programming experience (at least it seems that way to me). Thanks.

Comment: off site, I'm not completely sure.  It has been a *long* time since I was in an academic setting (and I got help with some code online from other coders on a [mud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LPMud) I played on back in the day). To that extent, chat rooms are probably the best resource - a way to get real time, interactive help with the dense back and forth that chat provides (and Q&A lacks). Chat on Stack exchange requires 20 reputation on *any* site (if you are having difficulty with getting rep on SO, you could get it answering questions on [others](http://stackexchange.com/sites#)

Comment: Once you have that 20 rep, you could go to one of the [Stack Overflow chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) specializing in a language.  I'm personally a bit more active over in the Programmers.SE chat room [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/21/the-whiteboard)... and we have heaped students with resources and instruction in the past (though as professionals, we're most active in that room 9-5, M-F; it gets quiet outside of that). Another SE site to look at is http://codereview.stackexchange.com for after the code is complete, how it can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

[String.compareTo(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) does this for you. It implements the [java.lang.Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings. The character sequence represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the character sequence represented by the argument string. The result is a negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the equals(Object) method would return true.

Example

```
System.out.println("apples".compareTo("bananas")); // returns -1 
System.out.println("bananas".compareTo("apples")); // returns 1
System.out.println("apples".compareTo("apples")); // return 0
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a shot! So I'll need to use an "if, else" command as well it looks like to get it to print out the answer too. I'll give it a try.